# How can I order on the sum of two fields in DynamicQuery

Tags: hibernate, liferay, liferay-6

I have an entity with two fields: pointsA and pointsB. I would like to sort on pointsA + pointsB.

I know how to do this with a custom SQL, but I would like to know how to do this with a DynamicQuery.

In hibernate, I would create an alias on the criterion:

```
criterion.createAlias("pointsA + pointsB", "totalPoints");
criterion.addOrder(Order.asc("totalPoints"));
return criterion.list();
```

I can't find how to do this with Liferay's wrapping of hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Okay let us suppose you want to sort between start date and end date on cloumn datetime on table Download_Details(custom table)
 You can perform it like

```
DynamicQuery downDetDQ=DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(Download_Details.class)
                                    .add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.between("datetime", startDate, endDate))
                                    .add(OrderFactoryUtil.asc("datetime")));
```

List listDetails=Download_DetailsLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(downDetDQ);

I guess that will solve your purpose